# Simple circle question

Tags: circles

let AB be diameter of circle and AC be the chord. Let a tangent is drawn from C  to meet AB produced at D.If BAC=30,Prove that BC= BD

SOLUTION

ACB= 90

ABC=60

CBD=120

After that I am confused

Comment: 3 theorems you should know. (1) Angles in semi-circle; (2) Angles in alternate segment; (3) Converse of an isosceles triangle.

Comment: What is an "alternate segment", and what is "the converse of an isosceles triangle"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember the theorem about the angle between a tangent and a cord at the tangency point, so you get

$$\angle BCD=\angle CAB=30^\circ$$

Using now that $\;\angle CBD=120^\circ\;$, deduce $\;\Delta BCD\;$ is isosceles and you're done.

Comment: can u pls suggest a book for elementery geometry ?

Comment: @godonichia, I loved Harold Jacobs' "Geometry"...and I read it completely while in graduate school. It is the first one here:http://www.abebooks.com/book-search/title/geometry/author/harold-jacobs/ , though I think there are new editions now.